# Running out of RAM with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, csv, ram

My code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob
import numpy as np

# Reading files and getting Dataframes

PathCurrentPeriod = '/home/sergio/Documents/Energyfiles'
allFiles = glob.glob(PathCurrentPeriod + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()

list_ = []

for file_ in allFiles:
    df = pd.read_csv(file_) 
    list_.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(list_, axis='rows')
```

However, files are about 300. I'm thinking I get a "killed" response from the terminal when I run it on VSCode since trying to get those 300 files stored on "frame" may cause the Virtual Machine where I run this to go out of RAM Memory.

Is there a work around? Is it possible to use the Hard Drive as the memory for processing instead or the RAM?.

The problem is not the size itself of each .csv, so that I could read them by chunks...the problem is that I'm appending too many.

Comment: Try to use Dask

Comment: What do you want to do? Can't you just analyze your data one-by-one or you really have to read everything into the memory? If you want to do some basic statistics (mean, variance), you can sum/loop over the files and you do not need to read everything in.

Comment: Hi @msi_gerva, what I'm trying to do really implies reading all files into one big dataframe. The problem is that, once I have the dataframe I create some groupby objects to get "statistics" as you are saying and some Exploratory Data Analysis, but that otherwise wouldn't be easier to do one by one.

Comment: As you are running on Virtual Machine, you have set some limits how much memory/performance VM can use... Perhaps you can try on your real machine - without the implicit limits of the VM - or get access to some machine with large memory.